# antlr match content inside brackets

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I need to parse the following

```
model { 

// any content, including brackets {}

var x= {} ; 

// any content, including brackets {}
}
```

If I do it like this :

```
model : MODEL OBR modelBody CBR;

modelBody: modelBodyLine;

modelBodyLine: TEXT* (OBR TEXT* CBR)* TEXT*;

TEXT : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'| '_' | '-')+ ;
OBR: '{';
CBR: '}';
```

I get this error

> warning(200): /SWL Parser/src/ro/sft/swl/language/parser/SWL.g:46:16: 
>   Decision can match input such as "TEXT" using multiple alternatives:
>   1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input  |--->
>   modelBodyLine: TEXT* (OBR TEXT* CBR)* TEXT*;

So what would be the best way to parse it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following `genericBlock` rule for these situations. This rule relies on your lexer to *at minimum* properly return a `CBR` token for the final `}` and to properly match a `CBR` token for every nested `OBR` token it creates.

```
genericBlock
  : OBR
    ( ~(OBR | CBR)
    | genericBlock
    )*
    CBR
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Problem is that if I try to parse something like `model { some text }` it goes into an infinite loop. The grammar is this : `model : MODEL modelBody;

modelBody: genericBlock;

genericBlock
  : OBR
    ( ~(OBR | CBR)
    | genericBlock
    )*
    CBR
  ;` . Hope you can spot the problem :)

Comment: another pattern which causes infinite loop: `model { var cv =; }`

Comment: You have a lexer rule which is able to match an empty string (such as `WS : '\t'*;` when it should be `WS : '\t'+;`) *and* you have some input which *no* lexer rule matches.